# Custom property name based on object under validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I have the following classes, they are bit simplified for example.

```
class LineInfo
{   
    Id,
    LineNumber,
    SubAccountNumer,
    MobileNumber
}

class SuspendLinesVM{
    public List<LineInfo> Lines{ get;set; }
}
```

I receive SuspendLinesVM in my action and all Lines are created dynamicaly from client. Each element that belongs to concrete LineInfo in form has name with template '**lineid{Id}_ElementName**'. So they comes to me in form like:

lineid0001_LineNumber

lineid0001_SubAccountNumer

lineid0001_MobileNumber

lineid0021_LineNumber

lineid0021_SubAccountNumer

lineid0021_MobileNumber

When some error occures while validation, I need a way to set the failed property as it came in request to highlight invalid fields in the view.

I left questions where I got confused.

```
 public class LineInfoValidator: AbstractValidator<LineInfo>
    {
        public LineInfoValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(m => m.LineNumber)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Line # is required").OverridePropertyName( ??? ) 
                .InclusiveBetween(1, 9999).WithMessage("Line # must be in range [1, 9999]").OverridePropertyName( ??? )
...
```

I need a way to do something like *(instance, propertyName) => return string.format('lineid_{0}_{1}', instance.Id, propertyName)*.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved with 'WithState' method. Thanks to Jeremy! His solution is here http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/278892

> **JeremyS
>
>   Nov 10, 2011 at 5:16 PM**
>
> Unfortunately this isn't something that is supported.
>
> Property names are resolved only once when the validator is instantiated, as opposed to error messages which are generated when the validator is executed. In this case, you need to inspect the instance being validated to generate the property name, which isn't actually possible - the closest you'd be able to get is to use the WithState method to associate some custom state with the failure:
>
> ```
> RuleFor(x => x.LineNumber)
>     .NotEmpty()
>     .WithState(instance => string.Format("lineid_{0}_LineNumber", instance.Id));
> ```
>
> Once you invoke the validator and get back the ValidationResult, you can retrieve this from the CustomState property on the ValidationFailure.
>
> Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're using FluentValidator, you should be able to set the collection validator on the SuspendedLinesVM object like so:

```
public class SelectedLinesVMValidator : AbstractValidator<SelectedLinesVM>
{
    public SelectedLinesVMValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x=>x.Lines).SetCollectionValidator(new LineInfoValidator());
    }
}
```

If you do this, then [as per the documentation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CreatingAValidator&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#Collections) you will get back a collection of errors which relate to the index of the failed property.

Comment: That's correct. But in your case for all LineInfo in my collection, each property name will be identical like 'LineNumber', 'SubAccountNumer' and so on. The View will not distinguish to which LineInfo an error belongs, and will not render errors at all, because property name must be like 'lineid0001_LineNumber'. If only it were so easy :)